# Change shape of point estimate in coeff plot R (dotwhisker)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, coefficients

so I'm working on this coefficient plot with the dotwhisker package in R. I have three different models, that I want to show in the same plot and each should have a different point estimate (circle, triangle etc). But when I try it with the code I can't seem to create different point estimates and also the legend "disappears". Would be grateful for some help!! Thanks :)

```
dwplot(list(hff3, hn2, hu2),
vline = geom_vline(
  xintercept = 0,
  colour = "grey60",
  linetype = 2),
model_order = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3")
) %>% # plot line at zero _behind_coefs
  relabel_predictors(
    c(ZExtraversion = "Extraversion",
      ZOpenness = "Openness",
      ZAgreeableness = "Agreeableness",
      ZEmostab = "Emotional stability",
      ZConscientious = "Conscientiousness"))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 4) + 
  xlab("Coefficient Estimate") + ylab("") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0,
             colour = "grey60",
             linetype = 2) +
  ggtitle("Support groups") +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.9, 0.95),
    legend.background = element_rect(colour = "grey80")
  ) +
  scale_colour_grey(
    start = .3,
    end = .7,
    name = "support groups",
    breaks = c(0, 1, 2),
    labels = c("Family", "Neigbors", 
               "Strangers")
  ) + scale_shape_discrete(
    name = "support groups",
    breaks = c(0, 1, 2),
    labels = c("Family", "Neigbors", 
               "Strangers")) +
  guides(
    shape = guide_legend("support groups"), 
    colour = guide_legend("support groups"))
```

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: for what it's worth, my *general* advice when trying to do complicated stuff with `dotwhisker` is to use `broom::tidy` + `purrr::map_dfr()` to get the information you need and then build your own `ggplot` (`geom_pointrange()` will get you 95% of what `dwplot` does)